# Concatenate columns in t-sql but exclude columns that are null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT 'Column 1: ' + t.Column1 + 
'Column 2: ' + t.Column2 + 
'Column 3: ' + t.Column3 
from Table1 t
```

So I need a custom string before every column like shown. However, if Column2 is null, for example, I want to exclude the entire part 'Column 2: ' + t.Column2.

Where clause to only show not null columns is not what I'm looking for, since it's valid that all 3 columns are null for some rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server, concatenating `null` to a string will result with `null`. Taking advantage of that fact, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT ISNULL('Column 1: ' + t.Column1, '') + 
       ISNULL('Column 2: ' + t.Column2, '') + 
       ISNULL('Column 3: ' + t.Column3, '') 
FROM Table
```

In SQL Server 2012 or higher, you can use the `Concat` built in function, but you still need to concatenate the columns to their hard coded description the old fashion way to take advantage of the effect described before.

```
SELECT CONCAT('Column 1: ' + t.Column1, 
              'Column 2: ' + t.Column2, 
              'Column 3: ' + t.Column3) 
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming [`CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-concat-null-yields-null-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is turned on (it is by default and should be), you can do something like:

```
SELECT COALESCE('Column 1: ' + t.Column1,'') + 
COALESCE('Column 2: ' + t.Column2,'') + 
COALESCE('Column 3: ' + t.Column3,'')
from Table1 t
```

If any column is `NULL` then `'Column name ' + Column` will be `NULL`. `COALESCE` then replaces `NULL`s with empty strings so that the outer `+`s are joining non-NULL strings.

Comment: I would add the fact that `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` is depricated and will always be set to `ON` in future versions of SQL Server directly to the answer, even though it's stated on the link.